in swift ios share extension possible multiple share extension in one project. if yes then how?
in swift ios share extension possible multiple share extension in one project. if yes then how ?
and how to access swift file in share extension inside used ?
please tell me?
I try to file > new file > target > create share extension multiple but not work only one share extension show in gallery inside share option

Why do you want multiple share extensions?  Even if it were supported, it would be a confusing experience for the user, seeing your app more than once in the share sheet.



Currently, there is a future working of a post in Share Extension. Now I also want to share the chat in the share extension outside the app.


So now I want to run both post and chat futures in the share extension.


So how is that possible?


Both posts and chats should run from one share extension.



Are you sharing from your app or to your app?  Since you are talking about a share extension, I presume you are sharing to your app, in which case your Share Extension is responsible for presenting an appropriate UI that asks the user if they want to share to a Post or to a Chat.

I want to share on my app. Like share WhatsApp message in my app.

An app can only contain a single share extension.  While you could use "File->New->Target" multiple times to add multiple share extensions to your app, only one of these share extensions will be visible in the system "Share" dialog.  Which one would appear is undefined.

Can you tell me how to manage both posts and chats with one share extension?
